# How can COMET/ Server Push be achieved on Google app engine?

Tags: java, ajax, google-app-engine, websocket, comet

I am new to both Stack overflow and Google app engine.
in a Java Web application, how ddo I achieve COMET, are there limitations in terms of connection timeout or if that is not possible, can a websocket server be implemented on appengine ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is long polling possible in Google App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616145/is-long-polling-possible-in-google-app-engine)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need server-to-client push, you have to use [Channel API](http://code.google.com/intl/en/appengine/docs/java/channel/) for GAE.

It not a COMET or WebSockets, technically, but it's same. And, I guess, I'll be functioning as a web sockets, sometimes in future (maybe it's already working, but i don't know where to get a browser that supports this feature, right now. Can anyone correct me there?). Btw, for you it'll be still same Channel API

Comment: Thank alot splix, btw If WebSocket is concerned, Chrome supports it.
FireFox supported it initially, but removed it l8r as a security concern.
there is a library, If u havent checked already, called Socket.io in JS.
that I guess runs on nodejs on backend.
it has a graceful degradation feature from,websockets to comet to polling.
and in case one is making a chrome webapp, a complete end-to-end V8 solution can be achieved.

Comment: oh, you're right, just tested it. I was sure that Chrome didn't supports it. I heard this story about security problems and was sure that both FF and Chrome have disabled support of WS. Thanks

Comment: Actually, it is Comet - Comet is just a generic term for long-polling.